# UNC path in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to add a UNC path to asksaveasfile initaldir? Currently I have my a path to my desktop and everything works well but if I change path, file does not get created. Here is code.

```py
def save_info():
    color_info = color_entry.get(1.0, END)
    print(color_info)
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir="C:\\Users\testaccount\Desktop",
                                        defaultextension=".txt",
                                        filetype=[
                                            ("Text File", ".txt")
                                        ])


   
    file.write("!StaticShelving1x3_zpl," + color_info)

    file.close()

    print("Please check printer")

    color_entry.delete(1.0, END)
```

Comment: def save_info():
    color_info = color_entry.get(1.0, END)
    print(color_info)
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir="C:\\Users\\rlee\Desktop",
                                        defaultextension=".txt",
                                        filetype=[
                                            ("Text File", ".txt")
                                        ])


   
    file.write("!StaticShelving1x3_zpl," + color_info)

    file.close()

    print("Please check printer")

    color_entry.delete(1.0, END)

Comment: Please don't post code in the comment section. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Yes I apologies for that. I couldn't find away to edit question. New to Stack overflow